# for-loop help getting wrong output

Tags: c++, for-loop

I am writing a code using classes and am getting the wrong output, this is my function definitions:

```
void PrintCard(int c)
{
    int Rank = c%13;
    int Suit = c/13;
    const char NameSuit[5] = "SCDH";
    const char NameRank[14] = "23456789XJQKA";
    cout << NameRank[Rank] << NameSuit[Suit];
}

CardSet::CardSet()
{
    Card = NULL;
    nCards = 0;
}

CardSet::CardSet(int c)
{
    Card = new int[c];
    for(int i = 0; i > c; i++)
    {
        Card[i] = (i % 52);
    }
}

CardSet::~CardSet()
{
     delete[] Card;
}

bool CardSet::IsEmpty() const
{
    return nCards == 0;
}

void CardSet::Print() const
{
    for(int i=0; i > nCards; i++)
    {
        PrintCard(i);
    }     
} 

int CardSet::Size() const
{
    return nCards;
}
```

This is my main

```
    cout << "Testing constructors, Print(), Size() & IsEmpty():" << endl;
    CardSet CardSet1; // empty cCardSet
    CardSet CardSet2(12); // CardSet with 12 cards
    if(CardSet1.IsEmpty()) cout<<"CardSet1 is empty"<<endl;
    else cout<<"CardSet1 has "<< CardSet1.Size() <<" cards" << endl;
    if(CardSet2.IsEmpty()) cout<<"CardSet2 is empty"<<endl;
    else cout<<"CardSet2 has "<< CardSet2.Size() <<" cards" << endl;
    cout << "Printout of CardSet1: ";
    CardSet1.Print();
    cout << "Printout of CardSet2: ";
    CardSet2.Print();
    cout << endl;
```

when i am compiling i am getting the correct value (0) for cardset1 however for cardset2 instead of outputting a value of 12, which is what should be the output i am getting very high numbers that are changing each time i compile. i think something is wrong with my for loops or memory allocation.

this is also what the class definition looks like:

```
class CardSet
{
    public:
        CardSet();
        CardSet(int);
        ~CardSet();
        int Size() const;
        bool IsEmpty() const;
        void Shuffle();
        int Deal();
        void Deal(int,CardSet&,CardSet&);
        void Deal(int,CardSet&,CardSet&,CardSet&,CardSet&);
        void AddCard(int);
        void MergeShuffle(CardSet&);
        void Print() const;
    private:
        int* Card;
        int nCards;
};
```

any help would be greatly appreciated !!

Cheers

Comment: The end tests of yours loops are wrong : i > c shall be i<c

Comment: Also you never set `nCards` in your second Constructor, hence it is uninitialized and thus accessing it results in undefined behaviour.

Comment: Also if you are using `C++` there is almost no reason to use raw pointers. In your case use an `std::vector` or an `std::list` or whatever but if you want to use raw pointers use `C`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In `CardSet::CardSet` change this

```
for(int i = 0; i > c; i++)
```

to this

```
for (int i = 0; i < c; i++)
```

Also in `CardSet::Print` change this

```
for(int i=0; i > nCards; i++)
```

To this:

```
for (int i = 0; i < nCards; i++)
```

Finally, add `nCards = c;` to `CardSet::CardSet`.

Comment: cheers this worked fine, also in the print function i need to make a new line after 24 cards have been printed. any ideas on how to implement that?

Comment: @ec1 to achieve this you can put `if ((i > 0) && (i % 24 == 0)) cout << endl;` into your `CardSet::Print()` loop.

Answer (score 2):

```
void CardSet::Print() const
{
  for(int i=0; i > nCards; i++)
  {
    PrintCard(i);
  }     
}
```

must be

```
void CardSet::Print() const
{
  for(int i=0; i < nCards; i++)
  {
    PrintCard(i);
  }     
}
```

to correct the end test, and you have the same problem in `CardSet::CardSet(int c)` which must be

```
CardSet::CardSet(int c)
{
   nCards = c;
   Card = new int[c];
   for(int i = 0; i < c; i++)
   {
     Card[i] = (i % 52);
   }
}
```

where *nCards* must also be set.

In a *for* the test indicates if the loop continues, not if it ends

```
for (inits; test; changes) ...
```

is equivalent to

```
init;
while (test) {
   ...
   changes;
}
```

---

Out of that there is no separator in *PrintCard* doing `cout << NameRank[Rank] << NameSuit[Suit];` so may be you also need to add something like a space in *Print* :

```
void CardSet::Print() const
{
  for(int i=0; i < nCards; i++)
  {
    PrintCard(i);
    cout << ' ';
  }     
}
```

or in *PrintCard* to also separate the two fields like

```
cout << NameRank[Rank] << ' ' << NameSuit[Suit] << endl;
```

Note you can simplify

```
const char NameSuit[5] = "SCDH";
const char NameRank[14] = "23456789XJQKA";
cout << NameRank[Rank] << NameSuit[Suit];
```

to be

```
cout << "23456789XJQKA"[Rank] << "SCDH"[Suit];
```

Or if you really want to have the arrays I encourage you to not give a size, that avoid problems if you change the literal string and forget to also change the size, so

```
const char NameSuit[] = "SCDH";
const char NameRank[] = "23456789XJQKA";
```

For instance having :

```
#include <iostream>

using namespace std;

class CardSet
{
    public:
        CardSet();
        CardSet(int);
        ~CardSet();
        int Size() const;
        bool IsEmpty() const;
        void Shuffle();
        int Deal();
        void Deal(int,CardSet&,CardSet&);
        void Deal(int,CardSet&,CardSet&,CardSet&,CardSet&);
        void AddCard(int);
        void MergeShuffle(CardSet&);
        void Print() const;
    private:
        int* Card;
        int nCards;
};

void PrintCard(int c)
{
    int Rank = c%13;
    int Suit = c/13;

    cout << "23456789XJQKA"[Rank] << ' ' << "SCDH"[Suit] << endl;
}

CardSet::CardSet()
{
  Card = NULL;
  nCards = 0;
}

CardSet::CardSet(int c)
{
  nCards = c;
  Card = new int[c];
  for(int i = 0; i < c; i++)
  {
    Card[i] = (i % 52);
  }
}

CardSet::~CardSet()
{
  delete[] Card;
}

bool CardSet::IsEmpty() const
{
  return nCards == 0;
}

void CardSet::Print() const
{
  for(int i=0; i < nCards; i++)
  {
    PrintCard(i);
  }     
} 

int CardSet::Size() const
{
  return nCards;
}

int main(void)
{
  CardSet cs(5);

  cs.Print();
}
```

Compilation and execution :

```
pi@raspberrypi:/tmp $ g++ -pedantic -Wall -Wextra c.cc
pi@raspberrypi:/tmp $ ./a.out
2 S
3 S
4 S
5 S
6 S
pi@raspberrypi:/tmp $
```

Answer (score 0):

You should review it (the loop)

```
void CardSet::Print() const
{
    for(int i=0; i > nCards; i++)//@@ reconsider it
    {
      PrintCard(i);
    }     
}
```